# Execute function when particular key is pressed if textbox has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to focus on a textbox which is located down in a webpage when a user presses the down key.
I know that I can do it by using the following code:-

```
if ( e.keyCode === 40 ) { // 40 is down key

    // I m stuck here

}
```

Now, I am stuck in what to code in the body region. How to bring focus to the textbox whose id is "abc" for example. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
I tried this :-http://jsfiddle.net/9qAqM/ (helped by @iBlue)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#xyz").keypress(function(e){
            if ( e.which === 40 ) { 
$('#abc').focus();
}         
}) ;

});
```

Still, its not working

Comment: hi...a small glitch in your code...i updated my answer to suite your code.have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/9qAqM/2/.

```
$('#xyz').keypress(function(event){
     var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
     if(keycode == '13'){
           $('#abc').focus();   
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

try this piece of code

```
$('#abc').focus();
```

or

```
document.getElementById('abc').focus();
```

***UPDATE::***
As per your code, since you are trying to detect the down arrow keys they are not detected by `keypress` event.They are detected by `keydown` event.So if you modify your code as per the below code it would work

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#xyz").keydown(function(e){
                if ( e.which == 40 ) { 
                        $('#abc').focus();
                }         
             }) ;
});
```

Here is the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5M4hd/) for your code

Comment: Srry iBlue...@Jyoti answered it before you...thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery try this:

```
if ($("#IdOfYourTextBox").is(':focus')) {
alert("TextBox is focused!");
}
```